# http://book-pages.org/ylodesm automatically opens periodically

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, virus

Whenever I connect my laptop to a charger, google chrome (my default browser) opens automatically with this webpage

> http://book-pages.org/ylodesm

and then this webpage starts opening up after every 15 minutes (roughly) continuously till the time laptop is on AC power. The moment it is discharging, the cycle stops and no more webpages open. I tried to monitor the change in processes list in task manager after connecting the charger but no known virus program found. Tried many anti-malware that cleaned the windows in safe mode but the problem is same (occurs only on charging).
Whenever I google this particular thing the answer always is a long list of anti-malware programs (same as on superuser). I have tired many but none of them did prove useful so far. 
This particular question is for only this particular type of malware (not to be confused with general virus infections and removal questions). Please provide specific answer if anybody has disinfected this particular Trojan only (again not the general virus removal tools)

Comment: Please the answers in the linked question for assistance cleaning your computer.

Comment: the above two links are no doubt good but they just provide a general solution for different malware. The problem here is specific whereas the antivirus and antimalware proposed by those links have failed to correct it. I asked this question to know if someone had specifically this error and which particular method disinfected the system

Comment: If you Google book-pages.org, you will find plenty of references to this malware and suggestions specific to it.  There are too many malware items in existence for the site to maintain specific knowledge on each one, and whole classes of malware have similar solutions.  The canonical thread is the most effective way for the site to be able to provide support within a reasonable scope.

Comment: nothing personal but I really had tried all that and asking question at superuser is the last thing I do in pursuit of unknown. And This google thing is what everyone including me does first before writing a long script of question and description on this forum.

Comment: In order to get beyond the basic antivirus question and the answers we have pointed you towards then you need to add MUCH more information. Right now all you have given us indicates a very basic malware infection. You are our eyes and ears, we can only provide the brain in this context. To begin with you'll need to clearly and concisely indicate how you've tried each of the above-linked steps and how they fell short, what you HAVE observed, and what you expected to find but did not. Start with that and we may begin to have enough to get you a more specific answer.